# React store data from a state into another state

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

can anyone please help me solve this problem, I am trying to get some attribute from the tempList state to store into listReceiver state by using `gosetListReceiver()` function below.

```
const [tempList, setTempList] = useState([]); 

const [listReceiver, setListReceiver] = useState([]);


    function gosetListReceiver() {
    let i = 0;
    while (i < tempList.length) {
        setListReceiver([
            ...listReceiver,
            {
                name: tempList[i]["name"],
                phone: tempList[i]["receiver"]
            }
        ]);

        i++;
    }
}
```

but when I am mapping/console the `listReceiver` state after that , I expect that it will store 3 array from the `tempList` into `listReceiver` but it only have the last item from `tempList` that stored into it. how can i fix this?

below the sample data of `tempList` as i need to take name and receiver attribute to store into `listReceiver`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time through the loop, you are overwriting the state and thus wiping out anything you did on the last time through the loop. To fix this, you have two options.

1. Use the function version of set state so that you always get passed in the most recent version of the state:

```
setListReceiver((prev) => [
  ...prev,
  {
    name: tempList[i]["name"],
    phone: tempList[i]["receiver"],
  },
]);
```

2. Wait until you've created the full array, and then set state just once at the end:

```
function gosetListReceiver() {
  let i = 0;
  const newState = [...listReceiver];
  while (i < tempList.length) {
    newState.push({
      name: tempList[i]["name"],
      phone: tempList[i]["receiver"],
    });

    i++;
  }
  setListReceiver(newState);
}
```

P.S, this code looks like it would be better as a `for` loop, instead of a `while` loop:

```
const newState = [...listReceiver];
for (let i = 0; i < tempList.length; i++) {
  newState.push({
    name: tempList[i]["name"],
    phone: tempList[i]["receiver"],
  });
}
setListReceiver(newState);
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't tested, but the array brackets `[]` at the beginning of `setListReceiver()` looks suspicious to me.

Try without them:

```
...
setListReceiver(
    ...listReceiver,
    {
        name: tempList[i]["name"],
        phone: tempList[i]["receiver"]
    }
);
...
```

Or a way which should definitelly work, have a look at `Array.push(...)`.